# Sorting list of files in an a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, sorting

There are many similar questions and I almost have the solution but I have a case that isn't sorted like the client wants it.

I am using the following function to sort my array:

```
function sortFilesByName($a, $b) {
    if (basename(strtolower($a['path'])) == basename(strtolower($b['path']))) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (basename(strtolower($a['path'])) < basename(strtolower($b['path']))) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

The problem is that I get the following order when sorting my list:

1. file2.png
2. file3.png
3. file4.png
4. file5.png
5. file6.png
6. file7.png
7. file8.png
8. file9.png
9. file10.png
10. file11.png
11. file1.png

The client would like to have file1.png at the top of the list and I have to say I'm a little confused as how to achieve that. Any help is appreciated :)

After the answers given I've gotten much closer, I changed my function to the following:

```
function sortFilesByName($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp(strtolower(basename($a['path'])), strtolower(basename($b['path'])));
}
```

And it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need the [`natsort();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function instead. It sorts alphanumerically.

```
<?php 
   $numbers = array("1.gif","2.gif","20.gif","10.gif"); 
   natsort($numbers); 
   print_r($numbers); 
?>
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
[0] => 1.gif
[1] => 2.gif
[3] => 10.gif
[2] => 20.gif
)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer lead me to right spot, posted my new function in my question.

Answer (score 3):

The `natsort` function will do what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php.

Comment: Thanks, natsort uses the algorithm that I needed which lead me to natsortcmp!